# Differentiation of a distribution function with respect to a measure

Tags: distributions, measure-theory

**The context is that**

> $X^{(n)}=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ consists of $n$ $i.i.d.$ observations according to $F$. Assume $F$ is dominated by a common $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$, and let $f=\frac{dF(x)}{d\mu}$.

**Here, I cannot understand the concept of $f=\frac{dF(x)}{d\mu}$.**

**How can we differentiate a distribution with respect to a measure?**

reference: Romano, Joseph P., Azeem M. Shaikh, and Michael Wolf. "Hypothesis testing in econometrics." Annu. Rev. Econ. 2.1 (2010): 75-104.

Comment: See the first half of my post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/491045/919 for an explanation and a concrete example.  At https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/470038/919 I also supply a definition and illustrate some basic calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function
$$f(x)=\dfrac{\text dF}{\text d\mu}(x)$$ is the density of the measure $F$ with respect to the dominating measure $\mu$. The notation comes from the unidimensional case when $F$ is the cdf and $\text dμ$ the Lebesgue measure, $\text dx$. It is also called the [Radon-Nikodym derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem) of the measure $F$ with respect to the measure $\mu$, assuming $F$ is absolutely continuous wrt $\mu$.